# How to configure windows 7 to use Centos as DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I have a CentOS VM that I have configured as a DNS server and a windows 7 VM that is a client. I have configured that TCP/IP settings and specified centos as DNS server and changed primary DNS suffix in windows as well.

Problem is I can ping using IP,but using FQDN doesn't work. When I do `nslookup` in windows I get this:
[image: nslookup on windows 7]

Here are DNS configuration:
[image: Forward zone]
[image: Reverse zone]

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of terminal windows. Instead copy the text into your question and use the code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your windows machine cannot connect to the DNS server.

- Ensure you have the correct address configured on the windows system.
- Ensure that the DNS server process is listening on 192.168.1.1.
- Ensure that the CentOS firewall is allowing inbound connections on port 53 to 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was the iptables blocking. I flushed everything and now it works. I know allowing everything is a risk, but this is just practice.